# agency.css "header-bg.jpg" shows in one website, but not another using same bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, header

One (Agency) website uses "header-bg.jpg" successfully, while my new project with Agency does not show the image.

Can I replace "agency.css" with "creative.css", and rename it back to "agency.css" for my application? Obviously, the code for header is not the problem, and that lies somewhere else.

I am sure that is what I am looking for, but need some help.

The code I am using for header-bg.jpg is the "standard" first "header" block found in agency.css for both sites.

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(../assets/header-bg.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: none;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

While this works fine in another site I have in production using bootstrap, it is not working for the one I am trying to build now using the same template.

Working site: http://2100solutions.com

Not working header-bg.jpg: https://agile-tor-17392.herokuapp.com/

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: The missing image is https://agile-tor-17392.herokuapp.com/img/header-bg.jpg - if you upload the image you want to into that location everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

That image doesn't exist - it goes to a 404: https://agile-tor-17392.herokuapp.com/img/header-bg.jpg

Upload it and it will work :)

Comment: I uploaded the file(s) both .jpg and .png to gitHub, then executed "git push heroku master" to bring them from github to Heroku, but it is not showing.  nor or the other images.  just a broken link.  the pictures are there in the respective folders and should work agreed.   The tutorial for this said to remove the /"images"/ and replace with /"assets"/.   So that is how it is set for the moment.
it is not working on the local webrick server either.

Comment: What could be stopping the header-bg.jpg file from showing?  All my code is good, the pics are uploaded and in local.  Is there another document I have missed, or line of code?  It works great in my other site.

Comment: Looks like it's working now - https://gyazo.com/1112dfed112f0721e599179c9a179b56 - you may have been caching the old CSS file with the old URL. Is this how it's meant to display?